# How to run a mutation on mount with React Apollo 2.1's Mutation component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

We are currently moving from [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/introduction-to-relay.html) to [React Apollo 2.1](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) and something I'm doing seems fishy.

**Context:** Some components must only be rendered if the user is authenticated (via an API key), so there is an `Authenticator` component guarding the rest of the tree.

In `App.js`, it gets used like this (obviously all snippets below are minimal examples):

```
import React from 'react';
import Authenticator from './Authenticator';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

export default function App({ apiKey }) {
  return (
    <Authenticator apiKey={apiKey}
      render={({ error, token }) => {
        if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
        if (token) return <MyComponent token={token} />;
        return <div>Authenticating...</div>;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

If authentication succeeds, `MyComponent` gets rendered.
`Authentication` sends the authentication mutation to the server when rendered/mounted for the first time and calls the [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) accordingly.
`Authentication.js` looks as such:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import React from 'react';
import { Mutation } from 'react-apollo';

const AUTH_MUTATION = gql`mutation Login($apiKey: String!) {
  login(apiKey: $apiKey) {
    token
  }
}`;

export default function Authenticator({ apiKey, render }) {
  return (
    <Mutation mutation={AUTH_MUTATION} variables={{ apiKey }}>
      {(login, { data, error, called }) => {
        if (!called) login(); // ⚠️ This seems sketchy ⚠️

        const token = (data && data.login.token) || undefined;
        return render({ error, token });
      }}
    </Mutation>
  );
}
```

That `if (!called) login();` is what is giving me pause. If I don't specify `if (!called)`, the UI becomes epileptic and sends thousands of requests (which makes sense, calling `login()` causes `render()` to re-run), but is that how it's supposed to be used?

It seems like the [`Query` component equivalent](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/react-apollo-migration.html#query-component) differs in that simply rendering it emits the request. and I am wondering if there is a way to apply the same mechanism to `Mutation`, which requires calling the mutate function as part of the render prop.

The Relay equivalent of the snippet above does exactly what React Apollo's `Query` does on `Mutation`:

```
// Authentication.js

import React from 'react';
import { graphql, QueryRenderer } from 'react-relay';
import { Environment } from 'relay-runtime';

// Hiding out all the `Environment`-related boilerplate
const environment = return new Environment(/* ... */);

const AUTH_MUTATION = graphql`mutation Login($apiKey: String!) {
  login(apiKey: $apiKey) {
    token
  }
}`;

export default function Authenticator({ apiKey, render }) {
  return (
    <QueryRenderer query={AUTH_MUTATION} variables={{ apiKey }}
      render={render}
    />
  );
}


// App.js

import React from 'react';
import Authenticator from './Authenticator';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

export default function App({ apiKey }) {
  return (
    <Authenticator apiKey={apiKey}
      render={({ error, props }) => {
        if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
        if (props) return <MyComponent token={props.loginAPI.token)} />;
        return <div>Authenticating...</div>;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Right or wrong, Apollo makes some assumptions about how queries and mutations are used. By convention queries only fetch data while mutations, well, mutate data. Apollo takes that paradigm one step further and assumes that mutations will happen in response to some sort of action. So, like you observed, `Query` fetches the query on mount, while `Mutation` passes down a function to actually fetch the mutation.

In that sense, you've already deviated from how these components are "supposed to be used."

I don't think there's anything outright wrong with your approach -- assuming `called` never gets reset, your component should behave as intended. As an alternative, however, you could create a simple wrapper component to take advantage of `componentDidMount`:

```
class CallLogin extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.login()
  }

  render() {
    // React 16
    return this.props.children
    // Old School :)
    // return <div>{ this.props.children }</div>
  }
}

export default function Authenticator({ apiKey, render }) {
  return (
    <Mutation mutation={AUTH_MUTATION} variables={{ apiKey }}>
      {(login, { data, error }) => {
        const token = (data && data.login.token) || undefined;
        return (
          <CallLogin login={login}>
            {render({ error, token })}
          </CallLogin>
        )
      }}
    </Mutation>
  );
}
```

Comment: That's good to know and "reassuring", thanks! I do see many use cases to mutations that do not happen exclusively in response to action. In fact, Relay, which I find much more opinionated than Apollo, does not make this assumption! I'll open an issue on their end to suggest running the mutation right away if first param of `props.children` is not a function, essentially what `Query` does. Maybe that's stupid and wrong, but I'd like to see where the discussion gets us. Thanks again!

Comment: For whoever stops by this, my solution actually causes `Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render' or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to 'componentWillMount'.` Going for the solution Daniel posted solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation for my slightly unique case and it works well:

```
const VERIFY_USER = gql`
    mutation Verify_User($token: String!){
        verifyUser(token:$token){
            token
        }
    }
`

class Authenticator extends Component {

  state = { redirect: false }

  redirect = (authStatus) => {
    this.setState({redirect:true})
 }

  render() {
    if(this.redirect){
      return <Redirect to="/" />
    }

    const { token } = this.props.match.params
    console.log(token, "the token sir")

    return (
      <Mutation mutation={VERIFY_USER} variables={{ token }}>
        {(mutation) => {
          return (
            <VerifyUser authenticateUser={mutation} redirect={this.redirect}/>
          )
        }}
      </Mutation>
    )
  }
}


class VerifyUser extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.authUser();
  }

  authUser = async () => {
    let userStatus = await this.props.authenticateUser() // call the mutation
    this.props.redirect(userStatus)
  }

  render() {
    return null
  }
}

export default Authenticator
```