# Using react-apollo 2.1 mutations with react lifecycle methods

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I wonder, what is the way to use new `Mutation` components with react lifecycle methods.

Say I've got a page where I use several react-apollo mutations. I want to execute another mutation when loading state changes from `true` to `false` to show a notification popup in the page corner.

With higher order component I would do that in `componentDidUpdate` method, but now with `<Mutation />` component I can't do that. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run a mutation on mount with React Apollo 2.1's Mutation component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456738/how-to-run-a-mutation-on-mount-with-react-apollo-2-1s-mutation-component)

Answer (score 1):

You can render your component in render prop function and pass mutation in props:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { Mutation } from "react-apollo";

const ADD_TODO = gql`
  mutation addTodo($type: String!) {
    addTodo(type: $type) {
      id
      type
    }
  }
`;

const AddTodo = () => {
  return (
    <Mutation mutation={ADD_TODO}>
      {(addTodo, { data }) => 
        <YourComponent someFunction={addTodo} /> 
      }
    </Mutation>
  );
};

class YourComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.someFunction({variables: {type: 'abc'}})
  }
  render(){
    return <div></div>
  }
}
```