# Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `Mutation`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I'm trying to write some information with Apollo into a GraphQL/MongoDB DB, but there's always an error on the mutation.

Maybe someone could help me :(?

I call the function with the needed parameters with this.addTracker(); in onComponentDidMount();

```
    addTracker(trackerModelID, Hash, userId){
    console.log("Typ: " + trackerModelID);
    console.log("Access-Tooken: " + Hash.access_token)

    var access_token = Hash.access_token
    var token_type = Hash.token_type
    var expires_in = Hash.expires_in
    var user_id = Hash.user_id

    const createTrackerMutation = gql`
        mutation CreateTrackerMutation($trackerModelID: ID, $userId: ID, 
       $access_token: String, $token_type: String, $expires_in: Int, $user_id: String)
        {  createTracker (
            trackerModelID: $trackerModelID,
            userId: $userId,
            access_token: $access_token,
            token_type: $token_type,
            expires_in: $expires_in,
            user_id: $user_id
            )
            {
            id
            }
        }
        `
         console.log("jetzt run")   
        return(
          <div>hi
        <Mutation 
            mutation={createTrackerMutation} 
            variables={{ trackerModelID, userId, access_token, token_type, expires_in, user_id }}>
        </Mutation>
        </div>  
        )
    }
```

Error Message:
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `Mutation`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Mutation (at fitbit.js:97)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from your propTypes definition inside of `Mutation`.

The error says `Mutation` requires children as a prop but there are no `children` passed to `Mutation`

you need to insert children there:

```
  <Mutation 
        mutation={createTrackerMutation} 
        variables={{ trackerModelID, userId, access_token, token_type, expires_in, user_id }}>
     [INSERT_CHILDREN_HERE]
    </Mutation>
```

Children could be JSX elements, text or something else, depending on what `Mutation` is expecting. According to the doc, `Mutation` uses the `renderProp pattern`. So you should pass it a function that return some `JSX`. [Here is a good example in the doc](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#basic)

Comment: Hm okey, so i understand. How is it possible to run the mutation directly on load?

Comment: I think your mutation is triggered correctly, You have to insert the result of it inside `Mutation` now. Have a look at how it is done [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#basic):

Answer (score 2):

As the error indicates, the `Mutation` component is expecting a `children` prop passed to it, but you're not providing one. Both the `Query` and `Mutation` components utilize the [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) pattern, which means the `children` you provide should actually be a function that returns the component to render.

```
<Mutation 
  mutation={createTrackerMutation} 
  variables={{ trackerModelID, userId, access_token, token_type, expires_in, user_id }}>
  {(mutate, result) => {
    return (
      <div>Your component here.</div>
    )
  }}
</Mutation>
```

Details about the signature of the render prop function can be found [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/mutations.html#render-prop), but broadly speaking it's passed a `mutate` function as its first parameter and then, as a convenience, a `results` object as the second parameter. The `mutate` function is what you call to trigger the mutation.

Unlike a `Query` component, which will run whatever query you pass it to on mount, a `Mutation` component will not run the associated GraphQL query until `mutate` is called. This is intentional, as most *mutations* typically don't need to happen until some kind of user action occurs.

If you need to run a mutation when a component is mounted, the component that's rendered inside the `Mutation` component needs to be passed in `mutate` as a prop. That component can then call `mutate` in it's `componentDidMount` method. That question has been asked before and a more detailed answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49456738/how-to-run-a-mutation-on-mount-with-react-apollo-2-1s-mutation-component).